# How can I safely downgrade from 18.04 to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, downgrade

A couple of days ago I upgraded my netbook from 16.04 to 18.04. 
Is there a safe way to return to 16.04?
My system is the following:
Memory: 3.8GB
Processor: Intel® Celeron(R) CPU N3060 @ 1.60GHz × 2
OS Type: 64 bit
Disk: 26.5GB

Comment: It is nearly impossible (or very difficult). But you can always fix performance issues by switching to other DE - for example MATE or Xfce.

Comment: What would it involve to reinstall 16.04? I have saved all the contents of the "home" and "desktop" folders. Is there anything else I should aware of?